# Inserting only unique values into an array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a set of values that I'm pushing into an array in the order they occur

```
$valsArray = array(); 

//I process each value from a file (code removed for simplicity) 
//and then add into the array 
$valsArray[] = $val;
```

How do I turn this into an associative array instead where the value gets inserted (as `$key of associative array`) only if it doesn't exist. If it does exist increment its count (`$value of associative array`) by 1. I'm trying to find a more efficient way of handling those values compared to what I'm doing now.

Comment: why don't you use an assoc array for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you loop thru your values you can do the following:

```
isset( $valsArray[$val] ) ? $valsArray[$val]++ : $valsArray[$val]=1;
```

example:

```
$valsArray=array();

$val="foo";
isset($valsArray[$val])?$valsArray[$val]++:$valsArray[$val]=1;
$val="foo";
isset($valsArray[$val])?$valsArray[$val]++:$valsArray[$val]=1;
$val="bar";
isset($valsArray[$val])?$valsArray[$val]++:$valsArray[$val]=1;

print_r($valsArray);
```

will get you:

```
Array ( [foo] => 2 [bar] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 6):

$valsArray = [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)($valsArray);

Answer (score 4):

```
@$valsArray[$val]++;
```

should do it for you.  New entries get added as a key with a value of 1, existing entries get their value incremented.  The [@](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) avoids an E_NOTICE being thrown every time this encounters a new value.

Comment: Will generate E_NOTICE level errors when the element doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @chris Unfortunately that's true, although it's a very good answer and came first before zaf's. I think for future readers with the same question, I'll choose zaf's answer since it's more complete.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize it generated an error.  Drat.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I would edit to something like zaf's but he already did that nicely so I'll leave mine as an example of the shorter less-nice way to do it.

Comment: Added the @ to make it cleaner :)

Comment: @Sparr, I'm curious now, which is better practice? Does the `@` just suppress the warning (i.e. it still gets triggered, just doesn't show)?

Comment: I actually used this in production code on the same day I posted it.  The @ suppresses the warning.  I prefer my way, since it's one line of code with one or two lines of comments, which imho makes it a lot easier to read for whoever has to maintain it later.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just `$valsArray = array_unique($valsArray);` when you're done adding? Or do you need to keep the keys in correct order?

Comment: They don't need to be in correct order so that's one way. But if I do it this way, I lose information about their count (e.g. `orange` was answered 5 times, or `apple` was chosen as an answer 15 times). With an associative array, it's possible to store their count as the `$value` of the `$key`

Answer (score 0):

Trying looking at the following documentation

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @tombom, i disagree. The link is to the authorative php documentation, which includes a great description + usage example. Spending time duplicating a durable resource is not a good use of time. If I was linking to some random no name blog....then I might agree. but in general, hyperlinks to focused info are quite awesome, and very appropriate as answers here.